# Canvas grid like system

Tags: javascript, canvas, grid

I am currently trying to improve my logic with making animations with Javascript (canvas).

I would like to reproduce this animation : http://codepen.io/interaminense/pen/QKxrpE

For the beginning, I don't want columns going up and down. I only want to place all the lines and make them rotate.

I wrote this code :

The constructor

```
 function Particle(i, j){
   this.y = 15 * i * 2;
   this.x = 15 * j;
   particleIndex++;
   particles[particleIndex] = this;
   this.id = particleIndex;
   this.color = "#000000";            
}
```

Then, place the lines :

```
Particle.prototype.draw = function(){
   ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
   ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 1, 15); 
}
```

I tried to put only one line :

```
  var test = new Particle();
  test.draw();
```

It worked perfectly. Now, for several lines I thought to do something like this :
for each row, i create X lines:

```
for(var i=0; i<4; i++){ 
  for(var j=0; j<15; j++){
    // First row, i create 15 lines. Second row, I create 15 lines...
    new Particle(i, j); // i and j for determinate the row and columns
  }
}
```

Then, I place the line :

```
for( var i in particles){
   particles[i].draw();
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/65pgy0gc/2/

Now, for the rotating, I think the most difficult thing is to rotate the object from its own center. I rode that I have to translate in order to change the transform origin, apply the rotate and translate back.
Something like this ? :

```
Particle.prototype.draw = function(){
       ctx.fillStyle = this.color;

       ctx.translate(this.x,this.y);
       ctx.rotate((Math.PI/180)*angle);
       ctx.translate(-this.x,-this.y);

       ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 1, 15); 
    }
```

Comment: When you call `new Particle` why not pass in "row" and "column" arguments, which then gets used to set the X and Y position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to reverse a transform is way to much trouble.

To rotate about the center

```
// x,y center of rect
// w,h width and height
// rot in radians
function draw(x,y,w,h,rot){
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,x,y);  // if you want a scale replace the two 1s with scale
    ctx.rotate(rot);
    ctx.fillRect(-w/2,-h/2,w,h);
    // next line is optional 
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);  // will reset the transform or if you
                                    // are calling this function many times in a row
                                    // can be done after all the particles have been drawn

 }
```

- For more on rotating [Rotate individual objects in canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36946547/3877726)
- And some general purpose [sprite renders that may be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37365352/3877726)

Comment: Cool ! Thank you. Is there a way to apply a delay to each object ? You can check out my jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/65pgy0gc/3/ . I tried to put a setTimeout in the requestanimationframe but it failed...

Comment: @Seabon I had a look and forked it to https://jsfiddle.net/blindman67/ysLf6gzr/1/ with some changes. The delay (guessing what you want) is just a counter per particle that counts down until that particle can rotate.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted ! Very smart ;p Thank you